# Upload App logo for Ios In react native

Tags: ios, react-native, publishing

How to upload App logo in Ios when publish app on test flight mode and app will created in react native.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Have you created app on itunesConnect? If yes then just add App icon there.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for advice:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, you have to generate icons of different sizes

**Then**, you have to add them to iOS Images.xcassets

Answer (score 0):

First create all ios and android sizable icon.if you not know what size of icon than use https://makeappicon.com/ site.upload 1024 * 1024 image after process nd you got the all ios and android sizable image.

than paste all ios folder image in Images.xcassets